# Existence of Analytic Functions Based of f(1/n)

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question, and I don't even know where to begin:

Do functions $f$ or $g$ exist which are analytic at the point $z=0$ and satisfy the conditions: $f(\frac{1}{n})=f(\frac{-1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^2}$, and $g(\frac{1}{n})=g(\frac{-1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^3}$?

Comment: $f$ certainly exists! $g$ I suspect of being trickier.

Comment: Ok...I assume $f(z)=z^2$? That's analytic at zero and satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take $f(z)=z^2$. For $g$, define $h(z):=g(z)-z^3$. Then $h(n^{-1})=0$, and by uniqueness theorem, $g(z)=z^3$. But it doesn't match with the second condition, hence $g$ cannot exist.